# Selección de archivo

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Necesito implementar en mi app Cordova un sistema por el cual pueda seleccionar un archivo de mi local del dispositivo mediante un explorador de archivos, y posteriormente poder gestionar ese archivo para terminar subiendolo a un servidor.

Actualmente mediante input type="file" de HTML he logrado lanzar el explorador de archivos de Android en mi dispositivo (tablet), por el cual selecciono un archivo (un excel de ejemplo) y mediante el FileReader puedo leer dicho excel mediante un blob.

Bien, el problema está en que cuando quiero gestionar dicho blob, puedo tomar datos de este, como el nombre, el blob en si, la ruta... Necesito la ruta, ya que tengo que situar este archivo dentro del dispositivo para seguir adjuntando mas archivos y posteriormente subirlos al servidor. El problema es que la ruta la marca como C:\fakepath\prueba.xls y no me permite gestionar dicho archivo ya que marca que no existe el fichero en dicha ruta.

Se que es un mecanismo de seguridad del navegador, sin embargo tiene que haber alguna forma de gestionar dicho problema, de saber la ruta, o de gestionar el blob para poder subirlo.

Yo había pensado en ya que tengo el blob, copiarlo a un directorio temporal dentro del mismo local, en una ruta concreta dada por mi, por lo cual ya tendría la ruta, pero no se como debería hace esto, ¿como podría copiarlo desde el local a otro directorio del mismo local?

¿Alguien sería tan amable de echarme una mano?

Muchas gracias!

Edito para añadir más datos:

Actualmente tengo para seleccionar un archivo de mi dispositivo el selector de archivos que abre desde el botón del input file de html, selecciono un archivo (prueba.xls) y a partir de aquí es donde tengo los problemas.

tengo el archivo blob leido mediante:

```
var selectedFile = $('#theFile');
input = selectedFile[0];

if(input.files && input.files[0]){
    file = input.files[0];
    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        var archivo = fr.result;
        console.log(archivo);
    }

    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Y el blob lo lee bien, a partir de aquí, para poder añadir mas archivos, necesitaría saber la url del blob anterior, su ubicación, para luego al guardar los cambios pueda subirlos con el FileTransfer, ya que necesitaré su ubicación. Al ejecutar:

```
console.log("Ruta: "+$('#theFile')[0].value);
```

La ruta resultado es:

c:\fakepath\prueba.xls

ya que por seguridad el navegador no te provee de la ubicación de dicho archivo en tu local... Entonces estoy pensando en tomar dicho blob y guardarlo de forma temporal en una ruta conocida, tipo:

```
var pathFile = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/";
```

Para poder luego utilizar el blob de esa ruta, por lo que necesitaría guardar el blob del input file, estoy probando con (Sacados de la web de cordova tal cual):

```
function saveFile(dirEntry, fileData, fileName) {

    dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

        writeFile(fileEntry, fileData);

    }, onErrorCreateFile);
}
```

y con

```
function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj, isAppend) {

    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file write...");
            if (dataObj.type == "image/png") {
                readBinaryFile(fileEntry);
            }
            else {
                readFile(fileEntry);
            }
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
        };

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```

Pero no consigo guardar el blob. Quizás esté complicándome, o no, y no he dado con la forma correcta. Cualquier información o ayuda será de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tienes que utilizar el plugin de File para poder obtener el path de donde está alojado el archivo y para subirlo con File transfer: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html --------------
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html

Comment: Hola, y gracias por contestar. Este problema lo resolví hace tiempo guardando el archivo en una carpeta conocida del dispositivo. Así puedo gestionar posteriormente el archivo sabiendo la ruta de esa carpeta conocida. Obviamente con el plugin FILE.